# Is there any way that the android user run the application from UK?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I am trying to develop an android mobile application. I have a function which different from country localization. It will only UK country and other. Now my query how I will check that the user run the application from the UK.I s there any option to check out this user run the application from the UK. Please help me how will I check this.

Comment: you can set locale from your device and start VPN in your device this is simplest way for test.

Comment: Hi Ajay .Thanks to your comment.I don't know it will correct way which you suggest to me.May be there have four country list on UK then what will be?

Comment: actually that's my opinion may be the correct way is not that what i suggest you sorry

Answer (score -1):

If you are having the current latitude and longitude, then you can get the complete address of your current location by the following code:

```
 String country="";

    try{
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lon,1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0)
        {
            Log.e("address",addresses.toString());
            country=addresses.get(3).getFeatureName();
        }
    }
```

It will give you the country, and you can run your function if the country is UK.